# rosserial Raspberry Pi AMA0

Tags: rosserial, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
i would like to use a raspberry pi 3 and a arduino compatible expansion shield which can be pluged on the GPIO header, so i would like to use the serial interface.
If i do so and starting roscore and after that the node:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I'm getting an error message back. But if i use a FTDI converter and connect them with the USB interface of the RPI and starting the node:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
```

again, everything is working great.

So what should i do to be able to use the UART/Serial Interface of the RPi?

Key Facts:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- RPi Ubuntu Image: https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html

  - Rosserial
- AMA0 / UART Interface

I would be very much appericate about every reply - Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287181/rosserial-raspberry-pi-ama0/) by [danielros](https://answers.ros.org/users/34420/danielros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-31**:
Welcome!

> I'm getting an error message back

Please update your question with a copy and paste of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't run `rosserial` any more because of its high memory usage on the Arduino, but I have used it successfully connected both to USB and to the UART. It's important to have voltage level conversion on the receive line from the Arduino. The Arduino will output TTL-level voltage on that line (0-5V), while the RPi only wants 0-3.3V.

My current robot uses an A-Star board from Pololu, which plugs into the GPIO pins on the RPi. It has on-board level conversion wiring points, which I'm using, and it works fine as /dev/ttyAMA0.

Be aware that by default the serial ports are only accessible by root. If you are not running as root then you need to add your RPi user to the "dialout" group, which is the group of the TTY devices.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/36679/nelle/) on 2018-08-09**:
can you please elaborate on this? do I have to change something in the arduino code for this to work?

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2018-08-09**:
Most Arduino-ish devices are 5V, while the Pi runs on 3.3V. The Pi input pins cannot handle 5V, so to use the UART you have to do voltage level conversion in hardware using a voltage divider or off-the-shelf component like [this level shifter from Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2595).

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2018-08-09**:
You don't have to change anything on the Arduino side except to ensure that `rosserial` uses the UART. I think you have to edit ArduinoHardware.h, as indicated in [this rosserial_arduino tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/NodeHandle%20and%20ArduinoHardware).